# Lodash _.filter by more than 1 key

Tags: filter, lodash

i have array of objects like such :

```
var chart = [
        {
            "IDACCT": 28,
            "LVLCOA": 2,
            "IDPRNT": 1,
            "NMACCI": "110-000 - ASSETS"
        },
        {
            "IDACCT": 76,
            "LVLCOA": 2,
            "IDPRNT": 1,
            "NMACCI": "170-000 - FIXED ASSETS"
        }
    ];
```

i would like to return object where my search (predicate) is based using two keys :

```
d = _.filter(chart,function(o,e){
                return  o.LVLCOA === 2 && o.IDPRNT === e        
            });
```

this doesnt' work. i need to provide maybe some argument to the function. the problem e is not recognize in the function.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it doesn't when you try to compare a number to an undeclared variable `e`. I guess you wanted to compare it to another number?

Comment: i guess so . e comes from handler event. any suggestion? anyway but when i console.log(e). it prints out the number

Comment: i'll update the arguments on the question. but e still doesn't recognized

Comment: What happens when you put a break-point to that line and when you hover over `e`, or when you do `console.log` at that time?

Comment: it log all the chart object index sequentially. ex: 0,1,2,3,...,438. note: i have 439 array object items in chart.

Answer (score 0):

In your particular case, you can just setup a chain with two `filter()` calls and do away with predicate functions entirely. Passing `filter()` object shorthands should be sufficient:

```
var e = 1;
var d = _(chart)
  .filter({ LVLCOA: 2 })
  .filter({ IDPRNT: e })
  .value();
```